# How to handle reformatting of nested function calls with multi line string arguments

Tags: python, formatting, multiline, oitnb

We have set up automatic formatting of our python code base using `oitnb`, using the `multi-line-unwrap` option in the configuration file. Before that we made initial pass on all files with `--meld` and appropriate `fmt: no` comments were inserted.

Although we use the unwrap option these comments were most often inserted round multi line strings with `.format()` function. This reformats without change:

```
print('first:  {a}\nsecond: {b}\nthird:  {c}'.format(a=1, b=2, c=3))
```

but we cannot really see if printed elements are aligned. We tend to use:

```
print("""\
first:  {a}
second: {b}
third:  {c}
""".format(a=1, b=2, c=3))
```

but this gets mangled using `oitnb` into:

```
print("""\
first:  {a}
second: {b}
third:  {c}
""".format(
        a=1, b=2, c=3
    )
)
```

And this is even worse when such prints are in a function or class method, as we then wrap with `dedent`:

```
def main():
    print(dedent("""\
        first:  {a}
        second: {b}
        third:  {c}
    """.format(a=1, b=2, c=3)))
```

Can we also unwrap the `format` arguments? Or some other solution for new code so we don't need to use fmt comments?

Comment: `# fmt: no` is not going to do anything. You need to use `# fmt: off`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to unwrap methods that are attached to the multi-line strings, but I will consider unwrapping that (or adding a new option to do so). Unwrapping nested routines where the inner one has a multi-line string is going to be more difficult.

What currently IMO is the best approach is to assign the string to a variable, with a name short enough to not cause wrapping in the function call line:

```
def main():
    fmt_s = """\
        first:  {a}
        second: {b}
        third:  {c}
    """
    print(dedent(fmt_s.format(a=1, b=2, c=3)), end="")
```

reformats the same (given you don't set the line-length to a very low value, and so does:

```
def main():
    fmt_s = dedent("""\
        first:  {a}
        second: {b}
        third:  {c}
    """)
    print(fmt_s.format(a=1, b=2, c=3), end="")
```

*Please note that both these versions `dedent` before applying `.format()`.* I find that his is almost always what you want as it prevents you from having to include as many spaces as your multi-line string has as leading spaces after any newlines that are part of your `format`-arguments. Your examples dedent after `format`-ting.